How to preserve data types when working with pandas and sklearn transformers?
While working with a large sklearn Pipeline (fit using a DataFrame) I ran into an error that lead back to a wrong data type of my input. The problem occurred on an a single observation coming from an API that is supposed to interface the model in production. Missing information in a single line makes pandas (obviously) incapable of inferring the correct dtype but I thought that my fit transformers will handle the conversions. Apparently, I am mistaken.
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

X_tr = pd.DataFrame({"A": [5, 8, None, 4], "B": [3, None, 9.9, 12]})
print(X_tr.dtypes)  

#>> A    float64
#>> B    float64

x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10.1], "B": [None]})
print(x.dtypes)

#>> A    float64
#>> B    object

The above shows clearly that pandas infers the float64 types for column A and B in the training dataset, however (again obviously) for the single observation it doesn't know the dtype for the column B so it assigns object. No issue so far. But let's imagine a SimpleImputer somewhere within a Pipeline to replace the missing values:
imputer = SimpleImputer(
    fill_value=0, strategy="constant", missing_values=pd.NA
).set_output(transform="pandas")

X_tr_im = imputer.fit_transform(X_tr)  # training
print(X_tr_im.dtypes)

#>> A    float64
#>> B    float64

x_im = imputer.transform(x)
print(x_im.dtypes)

#>> A    object
#>> B    object

The imputer does replace the None values with zeros in all cases, however, two things happened that I did not expect:

Column B was NOT converted to the dtype that it was fit on
Column A was converted to the unwanted dtype of object

This creates two unwanted non-numeric data types that lead to errors further down the pipeline. Even if it is not the task of transformers to preserve dtypes, in my case it would still be very helpful.
Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Are there any solutions available?

The issue you are running into is how pandas handles None in a column.  If the column has other float or integer values, the None is coerced to a numpy.nan which is an instance of float.  This coercion maintains the column's type as a numeric column.
However, if no other values are present in the column, just None values, pandas does NOT try to coerce the column to float, and instead keeps it as a column of Python object types, which is what you are seeing when you try to impute x.
To ensure your datafame's columns are converted to a numeric type before being passed through the rest of the pipeline, you can use a sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer before the imputer, and use a function that forces the date type to np.float64 before any other computation happens.
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def df_to_float(x):
    return x.astype(np.float64)

x_tr = pd.DataFrame({"A": [5, 8, None, 4], "B": [3, None, 9.9, 12]})
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10.1], "B": [None]})

float_xform = FunctionTransformer(df_to_float)

imputer = SimpleImputer(
    fill_value=0, 
    strategy="constant",
    missing_values=pd.NA
).set_output(transform="pandas")

pipe = Pipeline([('float-transform', float_xform), ('impute-NA', imputer)])

print(pipe.fit_transform(x_tr).dtypes)
# A    float64
# B    float64

print(pipe.transform(x).dtypes)
# A    float64
# B    float64


In your context, making a prediction on a new single input, I think it's maybe more natural to instantiate the dataframe with the correct types:
x = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [10.1], "B": [None]}
).astype(
    X_tr.dtypes
)


To add a bit of understanding the cause of the issue:
When fitting or transforming, most sklearn objects cast the inputs to numpy arrays (using the helpers check_array or check_X_y, which perform other checks as well). But numpy arrays don't support different types per column like pandas, so x gets cast to an array of object dtype. The imputer still inserts the float statistic, but the array's dtype remains object. And finally, the pandas-output setting wraps that array into a frame, but does no dtype detection or conversion and so the result has all columns of object dtype.

Thanks for the background on the issue. Your solution works only when the training set is present, which is not the case in my application.

@Woodly0 You can save its dtypes to a json (or similar) for loading in your endpoint.

Or, if as in this example, you just want to cast to a single type, replace X_tr.dtypes by "float" or np.float64 etc. In that case, you can even use the dtype parameter of the pd.Dataframe constructor directly (no astype).
